# Microcontroller freezes (or doesn't) when plugged into different outlets in my home

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, interference, home-automation

I have an ARM development board (Marvell ARMADA XP CPU) and depending on which plug outlet I plug the system into, the system will freeze up after a few minutes or not.

I found that plug outlets in my finished basement, regardless of circuit will cause the unit to freeze, while plug outlets in bedrooms will not. Anyone know why that might be?

edit: In case it helps, the power adapter hooked into the system is a:
Channel Well Technology AC Adapter. Model CAD065121. Input: 100-240V 50/60Hz 1.8A MAX. Output: +12V 5.4A

Comment: It's hooked up with a simple 12volt DC power adapter that it came with.

Comment: Do you know what kind of power adapter it is?  Perhaps edit a photo into the question.

Comment: Ok, added the information on the adapter above. Channel Well Technology AC Adapter. Model CAD065121. Input: 100-240V 50/60Hz 1.8A MAX. Output: +12V 5.4A

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are facing electromagnetic interference (EMI).

It seems that your power supply has grounding pin. It also has capacitors from either mains pins to ground pin as a filter. If ground pin is not properly connected, you get half of mains voltage as common mode EMI at the output of your power supply. This causes lots of trouble with unprotected modern digital electronics.

Solution: ensure good grounding of the power supply and/or EMI filtering at load side.

Comment: Any surge protector hooked up claims it's grounded and I did try without any surge protector. I measure 0V from the cold to ground lead and 118V from hot to ground so it appears as though all the outlets read correctly. I tried hooking up to a few different outlets (each on different circuits at the breaker box) with varying results. Livings room and basement outlets cause the freeze while bedrooms do not. The freeze doesn't happen immediately. Usually after about an hour. Any suggestion on how to further check for solid ground or what else could be an issue?

Comment: @Michael Are you 100% sure of the correlation between outlet and lockup? It sounds more like a programming error - perhaps timing between the main loop and an interrupt routine.

Comment: A surge suppressor is not an EMI/RFI filter.  It is the bare cheapest MOV hooked across the lines, and possibly line and ground.  Try a decent EMI/RFI filter, usually in a metal can with pushon or solder to terminals.